# Spectron opens Empty terminals during test run

Tags: electron, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, spectron

During execution spectron opens two terminal windows that are blank. First window is the application as I wanted it to be, other windows look like terminals without anything inside.

Currently i focus to the first window using focus().

Github issue link : https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/60

Does anyone have any idea what's going on ? is it a ChromeDriver issue?

Comment: Please try to deactivate developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for your comment . Its already deactivated.

Comment: If your environment is Windows here is a issue about it. https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of focus() with setAlwaysOnTop(true) helps.

```
 chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = app.transferPromiseness;
    return app.start().then( async () => {
      await app.browserWindow.focus();
      await app.browserWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue (just to clarify, on Windows only).

Apparently, was introduced as a [workaround for Spectron on Windows](https://github.com/electron/spectron/commit/d74b5a0ddf500747bce30629a8be239db82edcd1):

> The launcher binary written in go was frequently marked as a trojan or virus. A simple bat file should seen as more innocuous. See [#93](https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/93) for the problem as well as this bat file.

Unfortunately, a consequence of using a `.bat` file is the [unavoidable spawning of these extra empty consoles](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window).

The only known workaround is using `.focus()` like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rework launcher.bat to use the start command?
something like:

```
Start "" "%SPECTRON_NODE_PATH%" "%SPECTRON_LAUNCHER_PATH%" %*
```

Just eyeballing it.

Not sure about managing the exit fail codes but IIRC that does not leave up shell.
Full disclosure, I do not have this app and this is a drive-by answer. Hope it helps.